# Changing the value of part of variable - Python

Tags: python

I have a variable which has time in H:M:S format like below

```
 h2='00:00:01'
```

i want to change the H part in it to 10 so that it becomes

```
h2='10:00:01'
```

I tried the below code, but it dint work

```
h2.split(':')[0]=10
print(h2)
```

Output:

```
00:00:01
```

Expected Output:

```
10:00:01
```

How can i change the value of part of a variable?

Comment: take a look at the `datetime` module if you are going to be working with dates extensively

Comment: a) strings can not be modified in Python, you have to construct a new one. b) for any serious date or time calculation use a proper library. `datetime` is built-in, but there are others like for example `arrow` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close.

Try:

```
h2='00:00:01'
h2 = h2.split(":")
h2[0] = '10'
print( ":".join(h2) )
```

*If you can use the datetime module*

```
import datetime
h2='00:00:01'
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(h2, "%H:%M:%S")
print( time.replace(hour=10).strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
10:00:01
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean how do you edit a **string** in-place? You can't, python string are immutable. You need to make a new string with a new value. What you're doing is the following

```
h2.split(':')  # makes a new list ['00', '00', '01']
h2.split(':')[0] = 10  # mutate said lest so it now equals ['10', '00', '01']
# then you just send that list you made into the void, you never assign it to anything
```

Instead you need to create a new object

```
h2 = '00:00:01'
h2_split = h2.split(':')
h2_split[0] = '10'
h3 = ':'.join(h2_split)
h2 = h3  # optionally reassign your original variable this new value
```